# Modal working only on home page

Tags: javascript, get-template-part, media-modal

I have created a modal pop up using JavaScript.

The HTML for the modal is in a `get_template_part("content",`"contact")` file.

The issue is, only on the home page does the modal pop up Through a click method.

When I visit another page, the modal doesn't pop up open.

How can I solve this issue?

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
$("#contactModal").click(function() {
    $('#myModal').show();
});
$(".close").click(function()    {
    $("#myModal").hide();
});
```

Here, my HTML code:

```
<!-- Contact -->
<div id="contactModal" class="contactWrapper">
    <div class="contactText">
        <a><p>You think we're cool? <br><span>Let's Get in touch.</span></p></a>
    </div>
</div><!-- end blogContainer -->
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="143" title="Main Contact Form"]' ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. Can you please specify how do you output your script to the browser? Using an external js file or via `functions.php` file?

Comment: You may surely have to add more details so as to enable the community understand the real nature of your challenge. For now, all may point to the fact that it is only available on your homepage.

Comment: @JackJohansson, I am using an external file.

Comment: @nyedidikeke, there isn't much to it really. I am using the get_template() way of adding content to specific pages. The HTML mark up in is a content-contact.php file.

Comment: @Leroy I agree with the other comment. You might want to add some more details, such as error log of your browser for example. And please check your HTML output (View page source) to make sure the JS file and HTML markup are actually present on other pages.

Comment: Could have to do with jQuery's no-conflict mode. Try changing `$` to `jQuery` - https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-is-not-working-in-wordpress-solution/

Comment: @WebElaine, I have done that. I have a JQuery modal (with a contact form) on every single page. To avoid repeating the code, I have put it in a file of it's own titled content-contact.php I then call the function get_template_part('content', 'contact'); to display the contact form modal. On the home page, when I click on #contactModal #myModal displays and the contact form. This works fine on the home page. However, on every other page/post/category #myModal does not display at all. When I click on #contactModal, the click is not recognised (or no event happens).

Comment: Have you verified the HTML and JS are both on all of the pages where the modal isn't working? And have you loaded those pages with the console open to see if there are JS errors? If there are any JS errors coming from somewhere else this will prevent any other JS on the page, such as the modal, from working.

Comment: @WebElaine you have hit the nail on the head. There were errors in the console. At first I ignored this cause I thought it had nothing to do with the "action" I wanted to be triggered. I have thus removed the code that was causing errors. Which leads me to my next question, do you know of any tutorials I can use for a JQuery slider. However, I do not want the HTML to be in a <ul> or <li> format. I want one where I am actually animating a div.

Comment: @JackJohansson you have hit the nail on the head. There were errors in the console. At first I ignored this cause I thought it had nothing to do with the "action" I wanted to be triggered. I have thus removed the code that was causing errors. Which leads me to my next question, do you know of any tutorials I can use for a JQuery slider. However, I do not want the HTML to be in a <ul> or <li> format. I want one where I am actually animating a div.

Comment: @Leroy Do you need a jQuery slider? Search for `slick slider`, this does what you are after.

Comment: @JackJohansson sorry to bother you again. How do you enqueue the styles and scripts correctly? Change.com/questions/266635/enqueue-slick-slider-not-working

Comment: @Leroy Hello, no problem :) check your question please.